# can't get property value from object PHP

Tags: php, object

I am facing a weird issue with the following object,

```
$ban = (object) array('type'=> 'mute', 'reason', 'asdasd', 'curr_ts', 1614661389, 'timestamp', 1614751450, 'bannedby', 'shoyeb');
var_dump($ban->type); // shows 'mute'
var_dump($ban->reason); // shows null
var_dump($ban->curr_ts); // shows null
var_dump($ban->timestamp); // shows null
var_dump($ban->bannedby); // shows null
```

I can only get the value of property 'type' and can't access other properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the array into something like this:

```
$ban = (object) array('type'=> 'mute', 'reason' => 'asdasd', 'curr_ts' => 1614661389, 'timestamp' => 1614751450, 'bannedby' => 'shoyeb');

var_dump($ban->type); // string(4) "mute"
var_dump($ban->reason); //  string(6) "asdasd" 
var_dump($ban->curr_ts); // int(1614661389) 
var_dump($ban->timestamp); // int(1614751450) 
var_dump($ban->bannedby); // string(6) "shoyeb"
```

Answer (score 3):

[Please Refer Man Page of PHP Array for better understanding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) :

> values Syntax **"index => values"**, separated by commas, define index and
> values. index may be of type string or integer. **When index is omitted,
> an integer index is automatically generated, starting at 0**. If index
> is an integer, next generated index will be the biggest integer index
>
> - 1. Note that when two identical index are defined, the last overwrite the first.
>
> Having a trailing comma after the last defined array entry, while
> unusual, is a valid syntax.

**You have :**

```
$ban = (object) array('type'=> 'mute', 'reason', 'asdasd', 'curr_ts', 1614661389, 'timestamp', 1614751450, 'bannedby', 'shoyeb');
```

**And you're getting below which is correct**

```
var_dump($ban->type); // shows 'mute'
var_dump($ban->reason); // shows null
var_dump($ban->curr_ts); // shows null
var_dump($ban->timestamp); // shows null
var_dump($ban->bannedby); // shows null
```

**Because your object is as follows:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => mute
    [0] => reason
    [1] => asdasd
    [2] => curr_ts
    [3] => 1614661389
    [4] => timestamp
    [5] => 1614751450
    [6] => bannedby
    [7] => shoyeb
)
```

**To understand better follow below:**

```
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ cat test.php 
<?php

$ban = (object) array('type'=> 'mute', 'reason', 'asdasd', 'curr_ts', 1614661389, 'timestamp', 1614751450, 'bannedby', 'shoyeb');

# object contents
print_r($ban);

# for property 0
echo $ban->{'0'}.PHP_EOL;
 
[akshay@db1 tmp]$ php test.php 
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => mute
    [0] => reason
    [1] => asdasd
    [2] => curr_ts
    [3] => 1614661389
    [4] => timestamp
    [5] => 1614751450
    [6] => bannedby
    [7] => shoyeb
)

reason
```

**If you wish to access like `$ban->reason` then you need to define like below**

```
$ban = (object) array('reason'=> 'somevalue or null' );
```

**OR standard way**

```
$ban = new stdClass();
$ban->reason = 'foo';
print_r($ban);
```

Comment: You said its correct, but how ? The behaviour is totally unexpected and confusing.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh read once again I updated answer for better understanding, you're looking for property which doesn't exist